# Trigger modal from child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, event-bubbling

I am working on a vue application at the moment, that has a structure similar to this,

`<div class="characters">
     <Character 
         v-for="character in this.charactersToSearch" 
         :key="character.id" 
         :name="character.name" 
         :character="character" 
         @click="showMoreInfo" />
<div>
<Modal v-if="showModal" />`

I was hoping that I could attach a click event onto my `<Character>` component and show the Modal that way but that does not seem to work. So how would I fire the modal from inside the child component, when the modal lives in the parent component?

Comment: can't you just set showModal from inside showMoreInfo?  You can also use this.$emit to pass custom events, or use this.$emit('input'...) and use v-model

Answer (score 0):

You are on your way but are missing a couple of steps.

1)

Add a ref to your Modal component, you can call on later.

```
<Modal ref="myModal"/>
```

2)

Inside your Modal component, you have to add an open method, that shows it. Typically done by changing the `display: none`

3)

Finally inside your `showMoreInfo` method you call your `open` method like this:

`this.$refs.myModal.open();`